# in django delete a row in sqlite3 when the time exceeds

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

In Django is there a way to save `mobile no`, `otp` and `created_time` to DB and let DB remove row when the time `created_time` is more than 10 sec.
(like time to live)

Answer (score 0):

At this time, SQLite does not support that. You best bet would be to implement a background worker, which would delete all the records created more than 10 seconds ago.